# How to clip animation outside of div using clip-path?

Tags: html, css

This is a followup question to the one I asked yesterday.

My goal was to create a box and slide an SVG graphic through the box, so that as the graphic moved, you would only see the parts of the graphic that were in the box, and the parts outside the box would be hidden.  Here's the code that made that work:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="mydiv">
    <br><br><br>
    <a id="swipe1";><img src="https://www.benngrant.com/html5/shape1.svg" /></a>
    <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {background: #ffffff url("https://www.benngrant.com/wp-content/themes/Abstract_Dark1/images/Bottom_texture.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; background-size:cover;}
a#swipe1 {transition-timing-function:linear; position:relative; opacity:.62; top:10px; animation: mymove 7.85s forwards;}
@keyframes mymove{from {left:-100%;} to {left:150%;}}
#mydiv {text-align:center; background:black; opacity:.5; max-width:50%; position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block; overflow: hidden; border:1px solid black}
```

Basically, all I had to do was add overflow:hidden and position:relative to #mydiv to make it work, which was pointed out. (I get why overflow:hidden is needed, still confused why position:relative is, but oh well.)

This time what I am asking is this: Is there an alternate way to accomplish the same effect using the clip-path css property to define a rectangle that hides any part of the moving graphic that is not within the rectangle? Can clip-path in fact be used somehow to define where the browser is permitted to draw the part parts of the image that are within it, as the image moves around following the keyframes? It seems reasonable to me in theory, but I'm not sure how to begin to implement it that way.

Any thoughts? Using just HTML and CSS, but not JavaScript? That creates a result equal to what this does?

https://jsfiddle.net/91p21odc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff url("https://www.benngrant.com/wp-content/themes/Abstract_Dark1/images/Bottom_texture.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#mydiv {
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

#swipe1 {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  opacity: .62;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 7.85s forwards;
}

.clip {
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0%, 60% 0%, 60% 100%, 40% 100%);
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 150%;
  }
}

#mydiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  opacity: .5;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="clip">
    <div id="swipe1">

      <img src="https://www.benngrant.com/html5/shape1.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I notice that the SVG is cut in half, though. I will play with your code a little and reply back later - thanks! :)

Comment: @Sindyr not a half, but exaclt 100px ;) .. i made this as i didn't clearly understand what you need so i thought you want only the part of the SVG to be visible and animate inside the container

Comment: Ahh, no what I would like is to not need a /div to cut off the animation, to use clip-path to set a rectangle where the animated SVG can appear, so that when it runs first we see the tip of the nose of the image, then the whole image becomes visible, and as it leaves first we see the nose disappear as it hits the edge of the clip-path rectangle, then the rest disappears. As if the clip-path rectangle is stationary as the animation moves through it - does that make sense?

Comment: @Sindyr ok got it :) so you may check my updated answer then ;)